# Why does animation rendered using FFmpeg output as AVI folder?

Tags: video

I rendered my animation and my output was set to FFmpeg video (mp4), but it came out as an AVI folder with an AVI video, which was simply my unedited footage. Then I tried to sequence it with PNG files, but those files came out as black screens. The image attached is in the result folder. For reference, this was a video I edited.

Comment: You didn't attach anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your output settings are like this:

[image: Output settings]

Note that if you disabled the *File Extensions* option, Blender will not write the file extension at the end of the file. Thus, if you manually wrote `.avi` in the output file path, it will output a fake AVI file: the extension is `.avi` but the file is written in MP4 container.